# Python code that should error from asyncio.wait and be caught in a try clause is not being caught

Tags: python, try-catch, python-asyncio

so I have an event loop which will `run_until_complete` my `accept_connection` method

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def accept_connection(self):
    assert self.server_socket is not None

    while True:
        client, addr = yield from self.loop.sock_accept(self.server_socket)
        asyncio.async(self.handle_connection(client, addr))
```

my `handle_connection` method looks like this

```
 def handle_connection(self, client, addr):
     #removed error checking

    while True:
        try:
            yield from asyncio.wait([con.handle_read_from_connection()], timeout=5.0)
        except (AssertionError, PacketException):
            print("Invalid packet detected!")
```

finally my `handle_read_from_connection` (currently) looks like this:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_read_from_connection(self):
    raise PacketException("hello")
```

therefore this method should always raise an error and hit the except block of the try catch statement and print invalid packet detected. Instead what happens is I get a traceback!

```
future: Task(<handle_read_from_connection>)<exception=PacketException('hello',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 283, in _step
    result = next(coro)
  File "/some_path.py", line 29, in handle_read_from_connection
    raise PacketException("hello")
GameProtocol.GameProtocol.PacketException: hello
```

does anyone know what going on here? why is the try catch not working? and how can I get it so we can catch these errors

Comment: `handle_read_from_connection` isn't a generator because it doesn't include a `yield from`, so it isn't really a coroutine.  Try restructuring it by adding a `yield from` and then raising.

Comment: @NedDeily: the [`asyncio.coroutine()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3aa5fae8c313/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#l92) decorator already does it

Comment: So it does. So much for drive-by comments!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the returned values from `asyncio.wait()`:

```
import asyncio

class Error(Exception):
    pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    try:
        done, pending = yield from asyncio.wait([raise_exception()], timeout=1)
        assert not pending
        future, = done # unpack a set of length one
        print(future.result()) # raise an exception or use future.exception()
    except Error:
        print('got exception', flush=True)
    else:
        print('no exception', flush=True)

@asyncio.coroutine
def raise_exception(): # normally it is a generator (yield from)
                       #  or it returns a Future
    raise Error("message")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

#### Output

```
got exception
```

The current implementation of `asyncio.coroutine` assumes that if a function is not a generator (like in your case) then it returns a Future and thus it should be converted to be a generator therefore calling `raise_exception()` doesn't raise an exception because it just creates the generator object (the coroutine).

Then `asyncio.wait()` yields it and some equivalent of `future.set_exception(exception)` is done.

To avoid the error output that you see; you need to consume the exception either by calling `future.result()` or `future.exception()` directly.